# What would be the best and cleanest way to create a service function which needs to do two nested rest calls depending on each other?

Tags: angularjs, rest, promise

I'm using Todd Mottos and John Papas Styleguide and am quite familiar with both. Now I'm trying to create a data service with a function which needs to do two nested REST-calls, the second depends on the first. what would be the best and cleanest way to achieve this?

I did write three functions:

```
[...]
return {
    get: get
};  

var benutzerkennung = {};


// API function
function get(referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent) {
    return getBenutzerkennung()
        .then(function() {
            return getMasterData(referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent);
        })
        .catch(requestFailed);
}

function getBenutzerkennung() {
    return commonQueryService
        .requestBenutzerkennung()
        .then(function(response) {
            benutzerkennung = response.data.reference;
        });
}

function getMasterData(referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent) {
    // "data" is just a simple js-object filled with the three params, two coming 
    // from the controller calling .save() and one coming from the first request 
    var data = getFilledDataObject(benutzerkennung, referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent);

    return $http
        .post('./services/anStammdatenService/get/getANStammdaten', data)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
}
```

so you see that the Service-Method to be called from the controller is

**function save()**

and it does the first request wrapped in the function "**getBenutzerkennung()**" which is required for the next request, wrapped in "**getMasterData()**". Is that a good codestyle?

Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Avoid mutating variables outside a `.then` method when chaining promises.

Comment: This looks pretty decent. The only suspicious thing is the variable in the top-level scope `benutzerkennung`, but this might have been intentional. The promise chaining and style looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mutating variables outside a `.then` method when chaining promises.

> BAD
>
> ```
> var outside;
>
> function getA (params){
>     return serviceA(params).then(function(response) {
>         outside = response.data;
>     });
> }
>
> function getB (params){
>     return getA(params).then(function() {
>          return serviceB(params,outside)
>     });
> }
> ```

The code risks closure problems. If the `getB` function is called multiple times before the previous chained XHRs complete, the `outside` variable may not be set properly.

### Chain data properly

```
function getA (params){
    return serviceA(params).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}

function getB (params){
    return getA(params).then(function(dataA) {
         return serviceB(params,dataA);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! I dont know why i didn't think of this myself, like returning the value in getA and passing it as response to getB. Thanks mate!

Another followup question: Does it make sense to put this requests in the states' resolve because its a CRUD-Edit-Component for the "masterData" and needs the data to prefill input fields, or is it enough to leave it in the components "onInit"? I know the difference is that "resolve" is synchronous and "onInit" not, but if I chain the requests as above I do force an order, right? Or is it cleaner to put it in the states' resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the style guides you mentioned but in general I would tend to do something like this:

```
const get = () => commonQueryService
  .requestBenutzerkennung()
  .then(function(response) {
      return response.data.reference;
  })
  .then(function(benutzerkennung){
    var data = getFilledDataObject(benutzerkennung, referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent);
    return $http.post('./services/anStammdatenService/get/getANStammdaten', data)

  })
  .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
  })
```

If you like you could extract the functions you pass to the .then()s so you'll get a nice clean promise pipeline at the end. Something like this

```
const getData = function(response) {
  return response.data.reference;
}

const postData = function(benutzerkennung){
  var data = getFilledDataObject(benutzerkennung, referenzID, versorgungsfallIdent);
  return $http.post('./services/anStammdatenService/get/getANStammdaten', data)   
}

const sendResponse = function (response) {
  return response.data;
}

const get = () => commonQueryService
  .requestBenutzerkennung()
  .then(getData)
  .then(postData)
  .then(sendResponse)
```

You may offcourse use more declarative names for your functions.